# CSS advice for centering a YUI calendar

Tags: calendar, yui, center

I am using the YUI multi page calendar on my website. I would like to center this on my web page but I am unsure of how to do this due to the complex CSS I am not used to. I have tried adding margin-left & margin-right: auto but this is not working.

An example of this multi-page calendar can be found here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/calgrp_clean.html

Would somebody be able to help me center this calendar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely simple. You just need to define a width for the main div so the margin can center it. You also need to put a div right before the main div closes to clear the months so the main div has a distinct height/width.

Add this style to the main Div:

```
<div id="cal1Container" class="yui-calcontainer multi" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; float: none;">
```

And before this Div closes add this

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Now it works! Floats are pretty confusing at first, but often that's something that needs to be done. Other than that it's basic CSS.

Comment: Hi,I tried this but the calendar remained left aligned! Thanks

Comment: I clicked the link you have. I'm in chrome, so I right clicked the calendar, hit "Inspect Element". Then I found out that I had forgotten ONE tiny detail: You have to remove the float off the main Div. I've edited my answer to fix that small mistake. Sorry!

Comment: Hi victoroux. I did this: <div id="cal1Container" class="yui-calcontainer multi" style="margin: 0 auto; width:740px;float:none;"><div style="clear: both;"></div></div>. It does center however the grey background dissappears, leaving a grey line at the top. Have you experienced this at all? Thanks

Comment: Yes. As I said this is a characteristic of floats. You need to use that div AFTER all the calendars but BEFORE the <div id="cal1Container"...> closes. That way the calendars within that are set by float will be cleared. Feel free to give the check mark anytime. The answer works for sure.

Comment: Hi Victoroux. As pasted in my previous comment, I did paste the <div style="clear: both;"></div> before the closing tag of the calendar div?